# Python won't print what I tell it to

Tags: python

```
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2,
         "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3,
         "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1,
         "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4,
         "x": 8, "z": 10}

def scrabble_score(word):
    total = []
    for x in word:
        total.append(score[x.lower()])
        total_1 = sum(total)
    return total_1
    print total_1

scrabble_score('Hey')
```

Okay. So I'm trying to get it to print out the total. Basically this takes a word and adds up the scrabble score of the word.  For some reason, it won't print it out.

Comment: Your function exits at `return`. Swap the `print` and `return` lines.

Comment: Alternatively (and preferably) you could print out the returned result.

Answer (score 4):

`return` will return control of the program back to the caller.  Anything past it is (essentially) unreachable code.

Reverse the order of your statements, and your `print` statement will work:

```
print total_1    
return total_1
```

Answer (score 3):

This is invalid code - although it compiles, which is peculiar because other programming languages would flag it as an error on the spot:

```
return total_1
print total_1  # unreachable code, function ends with return on previous line
```

It should be:

```
print total_1
return total_1
```

In other words: a `return` statement must be the last one in any execution path inside a function.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify this a bit by either using a list comprehension or keeping a running total rather than building up a second list.

```
def scrabble_score(word):
    return sum((score.get(x.lower(), 0) for x in word))

print scrabble_score('Hey')
>>> 9
```

Or

```
def scrabble_score2(word):
    total = 0
    for w in word:
        total += score.get(w.lower(), 0)
    return total

print scrabble_score2('Hey')
>>> 9
```